# Dependent sibling subdirectories in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

My current project has the following structure:

```
root
 |- parser
 |     |- include    // a directory for headers
 |     |- src        // a directory for sources
 |     |- parser.yy
 |     |- scanner.ll
 |     |- CmakeLists.txt
 |
 |- preprocessor
 |     |- include    // a directory for headers
 |     |- src        // a directory for sources
 |     |- CmakeLists.txt
 |
 |- main.cpp
 |- CMakeLists.txt
```

Now I want to start generating assembly codes. I have to use `staticstack` and `codegen` (are classes which are going to be defined)  in the `parser.yy` and in `src`folder of the `parser` foler.
I cannot figure out how to do that.
What's the best practice in CMake to do this ?

1. Should I make subdirectories named `semstack` and `codegen` in `parser` folder ? This doesn't seem correct to me since as a CMake project gets larger the hierarchy will get deeper and if more dependencies are there then it would be a mess.
2. Should I make these subdirectories in the root ? If then what is the syntax in CMake to use sibling subdirectory ?

Comment: This is all user preference. I usually have a libraries subfolder of the root where I put all libraries. Also a Development and Utilities  subfolder. Each of these folders has multiple folders and each of those represent a CMake target.

Comment: I now see that second option is cleaner. But I can't find the CMake syntax for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If then what is the syntax in CMake to use sibling subdirectory ?

There is no special syntax for this since normal (i.e. not `IMPORTED`) targets are global. If you define a library in one subdirectory, it may be used in any other via `target_link_libraries`.

For instance:

```
# parser/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(parser ...)
add_library(proj::parser ALIAS parser)

target_include_directories(
  parser PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>")
target_link_libraries(
  parser PRIVATE proj::semstack proj::codegen)
```

The code for other subdirectories is similar.

```
# ./CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(proj)

add_subdirectory(semstack)
add_subdirectory(codegen)
add_subdirectory(parser)
add_subdirectory(preprocessor)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  main PRIVATE proj::parser proj::preprocessor)
```

I create and link to `ALIAS` targets to avoid a typo in a target name being forwarded to the linker verbatim (names with `::` in CMake are *always* considered targets and this is validated at generation time).